# What should I do after the "usebackuproot" mount option works on BTRFS?

Tags: linux, filesystems, corruption, recovery, btrfs

After changing a BCache cache device, I was unable to mount my BTRFS filesystem without the "usebackuproot" option; I suspect that there is corruption without any disk failures. I've tried recreating the previous caching setup but it doesn't seem to help.

So the question is, what now? Both `btrfs rescue chunk-recover` and `btrfs check` failed, but with the "usebackuproot" option I can mount it r/w, the data seems fine, and `btrfs rescue super-recover` reports no issues. I'm currently performing a scrub operation but it will take several more hours.

**Can I trust the data stored on that filesystem? I made a read-only snapshot shortly before the corruption occurred, but still within the same filesystem; can I trust *that*? Will `btrfs scrub` or any other operation truly check whether any of my files are damaged? Should I just add "usebackuproot" to my /etc/fstab (and update-initramfs) and call it a day?**

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will work for everyone, but I saved my filesystem with the following steps*:

1. Mount the filesystem with `mount -o usebackuproot`†
2. Scrub the mounted filesystem with `btrfs scrub`
3. Unmount (or remount as ro) the filesystem and run `btrfs check --mode=lowmem`‡

*These steps assume that you're unable to mount the filesystem normally and that `btrfs check` has failed. Otherwise, try that first.

†If this step fails, try running `btrfs rescue super-recover`, and if that alone doesn't fix it, `btrfs rescue chunk-recover`.

‡This command will not fix your file systems if problems are found, but it's otherwise very memory intensive and will be killed by the kernel if run in a live image. If problems are found, make or use a separate installation to run `btrfs check --repair`.